# Merge front end react and backend node js for production build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am new to react

I have built a react app and node js handles the back end. Now I want to merge them together when building react app for production.. While developing I started react and node concurrently. But in production app the node should also run when the app starts.. How can I achieve this?

Comment: In general this isn't good practice. If it makes sense to merge the front end code with the back end code then your back end code isn't really back end code, just an extension of the front end. If you've written some sort of node server then you should deploy this separately and have your react front end connect to it.

Comment: It depends on where you deploy it.  On Heroku you can add a proxy to the client-side `package.json` that points it at the express port (like `"proxy": "http://localhost:5001"`).  Then you add a post-build script to the server's `package.json`, like `"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",`

Comment: I would like to host my react app in regular servers like hostgator. Now my react production build is ready.. How do i upload node js / back end to the server and connect both front end production build to back end node js.. Note that my databse are stored in mysql database and node referes to those data

Comment: And if i deploy backend code and front end to the server how do I make sure that the back end code is running at all time